# Spring Integration Kafka not working

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am trying to explore Spring Integration using Kafka and Spring Boot. I am following this tutorial [Spring Integration and Kafka](https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/15/using-apache-kafka-for-integration-and-data-processing-pipelines-with-spring)

I am using the dependencies provided in that document,but i am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'compression-codec' is not allowed to appear in element 'int-kafka:producer-configuration'.
```

I think this is a jar mismatch issue, but i am not able to resolve it, i tried to change the version a lot but the combination is not working for me. Please find my below gradle dependencies.

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
compile('org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.1.1')
compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:2.1.0.RELEASE')
compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl:1.1.0.M1')
```

Please do let me know if you need more details on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very old article based on the 1.x version; the configuration has changed considerably - see the updated Spring Integration Kafka documentation in the spring-kafka reference manual.

Spring Integration Kafka (2.x) is now based on the Spring Kafka project.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/

There is also a [sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/kafka) but it uses Java configuration, not XML.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I have updated the versions for the jars and it worked, pasting the dependencies which i used.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following dependencies and they worked.

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-stream')
compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:2.1.0.RELEASE')
compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl:1.1.0.M1')
```